# How can I post object as JSON for adding from Jax RS Client to server

Tags: java, json, rest, post, client

I try to learn rest webservice in java. I wrote a server jboss. I can get a list from server but I can't post a object to server. I try to post with restclient. This is successful. First block is get, second block is post and final block is request from client. Client project is normal java project. It is not web, jboss or it has not like jackson lib. 
How can I post object as JSON for adding from Jax RS Client to server?

```
@GET
@Path("/categories")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<CategoryVO> getAllCategories(){
    List<Category> cats =  entityManager.createQuery("select c from Category c").getResultList();       
    ArrayList<CategoryVO> results = new ArrayList<CategoryVO>();        
    for (Category c : cats) {
        results.add(new CategoryVO(c.getTitle(), c.getId()));
    }       
    return results;
}

@POST
@Path("/categoryAdd")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void saveCategory(CategoryVO catVO){
    System.out.println("Save Method is running");
    Category cat = new Category(catVO.getTitle());
    entityManager.persist(cat);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    URL url = null;
    HttpURLConnection con;
    try {
        url = new URL(
                "http://localhost:8080/RestWS/rest/NetasRestWS/categories");
        con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();     
        InputStreamReader reader =  new InputStreamReader( con.getInputStream());
        while(true){
                int x =reader.read();
                if(x==-1)
                    break;
                System.out.print((char)x);
        }           
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the goal of the code? Where does it have to generate JSON code?

Comment: My goalis to learn rest web service. I can write get methods from client with Java SE, but I can not post. I want to save a data as category. Category is created on client. I want to post as JSON.

Comment: The client post the categories to the server? Or the server send them to the client ?